# How to create an opera mail label that shows all messages in a folder

Tags: opera

I'm trying to emulate Thunderbird's QuickFolders functionality in Opera Mail Panels by creatin a label and having it only match messages in a particular folder.

I didnt setup any rules, because I want to match all messages in that folder.

But when I select the label, I dont see any messages.

**UPDATE** - the reason I am not updating by selecting the folder is I have a lot of folders - that is what QuickFolders does for Thunderbird and I need similar functionality in Opera Mail.

Comment: What steps did you take to try setting up your label? And why not just select the folder to see messages in it, if I may ask?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you "didn't set up any rules" because you "want to match all messages in that folder".

What you need to do is set up at least a dummy rule to match all messages (typically done with a rule that the *From* field includes "@" or similar - not the most intuitive thing, I agree). You may also need to uncheck "Apply rules only to new messages" on the label's Options tab if you want to retrospectively apply your rule to existing messages.

More details can be found in [Opera's sort mail tutorial](http://www.opera.com/browser/tutorials/mail/sort/).